# AHK need help to make a AHK gui button to run 3 different scripts

Tags: autohotkey

New to programming and AHK need help to build AHK GUI with at least three buttons to run 3 different scripts, and to show color in the button could be green to show that the script is running and if I click again to make it stop so becomes red. I have something but I would like to add like a color to the buttons to know that the script is not running or it is.

```
Gui, Add, Button, w200 h50 gTest1 , Run test1.AHK Script
Gui, Add, Button, w200 h50 gTest2 , Run test2.AHK Script
Gui, Show,, Print Options
Return

Test1:
Run combine_scripts.ahk
Return

Test2:
Run fast.ahk
Return
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
#NoEnv
#SingleInstance Force
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

DetectHiddenWindows On
SetTitleMatchMode 2

If WinExist("Script1.ahk - AutoHotkey v1 ahk_class AutoHotkey")
    S1 := true
else
    S1 := false
If WinExist("Script2.ahk - AutoHotkey v1 ahk_class AutoHotkey")
    S2 := true
else
    S2 := false
If WinExist("Script3.ahk - AutoHotkey v1 ahk_class AutoHotkey")
    S3 := true
else
    S3 := false

Gui -Caption +AlwaysOnTop 
Gui, Font, s12, Verdana 

If (S1)
{
    Gui, Add, Button, x5 w70 h20 gRunStopScript1, Stop
    Gui, Add, Progress, vA1 x80 ym w300 h20 cGreen, 100
}
else
{
    Gui, Add, Button, x5 w70 h20 gRunStopScript1, Run
    Gui, Add, Progress, vA1 x80 ym w300 h20 cRed, 100
}
Gui, Add, Text, xp+20 vB1 w200 cWhite +BackgroundTrans, Script1.ahk

If (S2)
{
    Gui, Add, Button, x5 w70 h20 gRunStopScript2, Stop
    Gui, Add, Progress, vA2 x80 y37 w300 h20 cGreen, 100
}
else
{
    Gui, Add, Button, x5 w70 h20 gRunStopScript2, Run
    Gui, Add, Progress, vA2 x80 y37 w300 h20 cRed, 100
}
Gui, Add, Text, xp+20 vB2 w200 cWhite +BackgroundTrans, Script2.ahk

If (S3)
{
    Gui, Add, Button, x5 w70 h20 gRunStopScript3, Stop
    Gui, Add, Progress, vA3 x80 y67 w300 h20 cGreen, 100
}
else
{
    Gui, Add, Button, x5 w70 h20 gRunStopScript3, Run
    Gui, Add, Progress, vA3 x80 y67 w300 h20 cRed, 100
}
Gui, Add, Text, xp+20 vB3 w200 cWhite +BackgroundTrans, Script3.ahk

SetTimer, ReloadScript, 1000 

Gui, Show, x10 y10, Run/Stop a Script
Return

RunStopScript1:
If (S1)
    WinClose, Script1.ahk - AutoHotkey v1 ahk_class AutoHotkey
else
    Run, Script1.ahk
Reload
Return

RunStopScript2:
If (S2)
    WinClose, Script2.ahk - AutoHotkey v1 ahk_class AutoHotkey
else
    Run, Script2.ahk
Reload
Return

RunStopScript3:
If (S3)
    WinClose, Script3.ahk - AutoHotkey v1 ahk_class AutoHotkey
else
    Run, Script3.ahk
Reload
Return

ReloadScript:
If (S1)
{
    If !WinExist("Script1.ahk - AutoHotkey v1 ahk_class AutoHotkey")
        Reload
}
else
{
    If WinExist("Script1.ahk - AutoHotkey v1 ahk_class AutoHotkey")
        Reload
}
If (S2)
{
    If !WinExist("Script2.ahk - AutoHotkey v1 ahk_class AutoHotkey")
        Reload
}
else
{
    If WinExist("Script2.ahk - AutoHotkey v1 ahk_class AutoHotkey")
        Reload
}
If (S3)
{
    If !WinExist("Script3.ahk - AutoHotkey v1 ahk_class AutoHotkey")
        Reload
}
else
{
    If WinExist("Script3.ahk - AutoHotkey v1 ahk_class AutoHotkey")
        Reload
}
Return
```

Comment: Ty friend I will try it.